# Uniswap/PancakeSwap automatically manage tokens with different amount of decimals (swap)?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, swaps, uniswapv2

I'm getting number results that do not make sense for me, when executing swap functions with USDT (in Uniswap V2 and PancakeSwap V2), and I noticed that USDT Token has only 6 decimals, instead of 18 (the standard number).

Do we need to make any conversion or fix in order to swap tokens with different amount of decimals?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to normalize both amounts to 18 decimals. See [ERC20Normalizer](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-contracts/blob/a82833ddff11797b7c8ff997aa3aade25e11af44/src/token/erc20/ERC20Normalizer.sol) and [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math).

Comment: And what's the main benefit of normalizing both amounts when swapping?